# QTimer replacement?

Tags: c++, qt

im currently trying to make a snake game to learn more about QT & c++ however when i try moving my QGraphicsRectItem Item automatically it changes speed.
My Question is there a better way to move an Item Automatically without QTimer?

This is My PressKeyEvent Method :

```
if(event->key()==Qt::Key_Left)
{
    setPos(x()-10,y());
    left=true;
}
else if(event->key()==Qt::Key_Right)
{
    setPos(x()+10,y());
    right=true;
}
if(event->key()==Qt::Key_Up)
{
    setPos(x(),y()-10);
    up=true;

}
if(event->key()==Qt::Key_Down)
{
    setPos(x(),y()+10);
    down=true;
}

    QTimer* timer=new QTimer();
    connect(timer,SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(move()));
    timer->start(10000);}
```

And Here is The Move method :

```
void Player::move()
{
    if(up==true)
    {
        setPos(x(),y()-10);
    }
    else if(down==true)
    {
        setPos(x(),y()+10);
    }
    else if(right==true)
    {
        setPos(x()+10,y());
    }
    else if(left==true)
    {
        setPos(x()-10,y());
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably want a single shot here instead of multiple timers calling move every 10 seconds. Although with that said I am not sure you want move to be called 10 seconds after a key press anyways.

Comment: Just tried it but it doesn't change the fact that the Item speeds up after a certain time :/

Comment: Even with single shot you have a new timer added for each key press. That is not what you want either.

Comment: Why not have one `QTimer` connected to `move()`. Make the connection in the constructor and just let it call `move()` all the time. The reason for the change in speed is obviously because you are created multiple timers and not making any disconnects or deallocations for the previously allocated timers.

Comment: What does `setPos()` do? Does it instantaneously move your object does it have some animation (with another `QTimer`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `QTimer` you create in `PressKeyEvent()` is dynamic allocation. It exists until you explicitly destroy it.

You are starting a new `QTimer` for every key press, but not destroying the previously created `QTimer`(s). So the speed of the snake will roughly double for every key press (in an ideal world).

The proper design would be to have only one `QTimer`. Make only one connection.

```
Constructor()
{
    QTimer* timer=new QTimer(this);
    connect(timer,SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(move()));
    timer->start(10000);
}

PressKeyEvent(){
if(event->key()==Qt::Key_Left)
{
    setPos(x()-10,y());
    left=true;
}
else if(event->key()==Qt::Key_Right)
{
    setPos(x()+10,y());
    right=true;
}
if(event->key()==Qt::Key_Up)
{
    setPos(x(),y()-10);
    up=true;

}
if(event->key()==Qt::Key_Down)
{
    setPos(x(),y()+10);
    down=true;
}
}

void Player::move()
{
    if(up==true)
    {
        setPos(x(),y()-10);
    }
    else if(down==true)
    {
        setPos(x(),y()+10);
    }
    else if(right==true)
    {
        setPos(x()+10,y());
    }
    else if(left==true)
    {
        setPos(x()-10,y());
    }
}
```

---

## Another Approach

If you want the game to start on the first key press, you can initialize a `bool` in the class and have a condition in your code:

```
PressKeyEvent()
{
if(event->key()==Qt::Key_Left)
{
    setPos(x()-10,y());
    left=true;
}
else if(event->key()==Qt::Key_Right)
{
    setPos(x()+10,y());
    right=true;
}
if(event->key()==Qt::Key_Up)
{
    setPos(x(),y()-10);
    up=true;

}
if(event->key()==Qt::Key_Down)
{
    setPos(x(),y()+10);
    down=true;
}
if (!gameStarted){
    gameStarted = true;
    QTimer* timer=new QTimer(this);
    connect(timer,SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(move()));
    timer->start(10000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use QTimer::singleshot() to not create the instance unnecessarily?

Comment: `QTimer:singleShot()` invokes the slot only once, doesn't it? In this case, you want the snake to move repeatedly?

Comment: You can still use `QTimer::singleShot()`, but that would involve a recursive `QTimer::singleShot()` within the slot to call itself again. Not a good choice as it is redundant.

Comment: Yes, what you say is correct, another thing is that I recommend that you handle the elimination of the memory of the QTimer created.

Comment: @eyllanesc True, I added that suggestion just before you commented :)

Comment: When a response is published, it should try to eliminate that type of errors, in SO we require a quality response, for example, pass `this` as a parent and Qt will do the job.

Comment: and if Qt5 is being used it is advisable to use the new connection syntax between the slots and the signals. :D

Comment: even when putting it in the constructor the speed still double :/

Comment: Then you will have to show more of your code. What does your constructor and `setPos()`  look like?

Comment: @ChadiTo, why you are not resetting the timer in PressKeyEvent() ? automatic move() and PressKeyEvent() motion are both in same direction, is this what you intend?